# Error enabling splitcell/splitcell extension for jupyter notebooks

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

If I want split slides into two columns in my rise presentation, I have to install the jupyter_contrib_nbextensions:

`pip install jupyter_contrib_nbextensions`

but, I can't be enabled by running:

`jupyter nbextension enable splitcell/splitcell`

with this problem

```
Enabling notebook extension splitcell/splitcell...
      - Validating: problems found:
        - require?  X splitcell/splitcell
```

Some solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you add the nbextensions to jupyter by running

```
jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
```

or similar? See [Step 2 of the nbextensions README](https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/blob/master/README.md#2-install-javascript-and-css-files).